# react-bootstrap progress bar - can you change the label color?

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-bootstrap to make a [progress bar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/). Easy enough, it works:

```
<ProgressBar className="progress" striped now={this.state.now} 
label={this.state.progress + "/" + this.state.total}/>
```

But the label text is white. I referenced the link above and search through their short docs, but couldn't find the option. **Is it possible to change the label's color?**

Comment: Per documentation the `label` property accepts a `node`, so you could try wrapping your text in a span and style that span with `color: white`.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to assign a `variant` property, for example in React you can do the following:

```
<ProgressBar now={score} variant="SOME_NAME" />
```

Write the CSS class like so:

```css
.bg-SOME_NAME{
  background-color: #123445!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Bootstrap components allow for custom variants, in your css you can define something like

```
{`
  .progress-custom {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
  }
`}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
<ProgressBar variant="custom" />
```

[You can read more about custom variants here.](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/theming/)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. In addition to changing the color of the bar, I wanted to not have a border radius.

I set the following global styles in my styles file.

```
`
// this is for the bar container
background: #F8F8F8; 
border: 0px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
border-radius: 0px; 
height: 16px;

.progress-bar {  // this is for the bar itself
  background-color: #4AA69F;
}
`
```

And I didn't change anything with the code. Yes, it did work.

```
const now = 25
const ProgressInstance = () => <ProgressBar now={now} />
```

[image]